# What is the time complexity of sliding and grouped functions of list in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am using sliding function of scala on a list and after drilling, it gives GroupedIterator.

I am wandering, what is the time complexity of funtions sliding and grouped?

```
val list = (1 to 10).toList

list.iterator.grouped(3).foreach(println(_))
list.grouped(11).foreach(println(_))
val st = (1 to 7).iterator.grouped(3).withPartial(false).toList
st
list.sliding(3).foreach(println(_))
list.sliding(11).foreach(println(_))


list.sliding(3,2).foreach(println(_))
list.sliding(11,2).foreach(println(_))
```

Seems grouped takes O(n) and sliding takes O(n*n).

Comment: Were are you getting those complexity values from?

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by time complexity of those functions? I'm pretty sure they are O(1) since they return an `Iterator`.

Comment: @Jasper-M Can you explain how it is O(1), since the iterators use internally hasNext(), next() and while loop to go over the list.

Comment: Because an Iterator is lazy. Calling `sliding` can return an Iterator in constant time.

Answer (score 3):

They are both `O(n)`

Grouped is clearly `O(n)` because it touches each element once.

Sliding is also `O(n)` because the number of times it touches each element is a constant. The fact that it touches the elements more than once does not affect the complexity.